# Component should be written as a pure function

Tags: eslint, react-native, pure-function

I have a react-native android application. My component in index.android.js is stateless so eslint is throwing the error "Component should be written as a pure function". If I make the component as pure function, how do i register the application or how should the instantiation be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESLint - Component should be written as a pure function (react prefer/stateless function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378911/eslint-component-should-be-written-as-a-pure-function-react-prefer-stateless)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register the application even with a "pure function"
This kind of code would work

```
 const App = () => {
  return (
    <MainApp />
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => App);
```

The "return" part can be deleted for a cleaner code:

```
const App = () => (
    <MainApp />
);


AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => App);
```

Comment: Great! If it works, don't hesitate to flag this answer as accepted :)