# ESLint - Component should be written as a pure function (react prefer/stateless function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

ESLint is giving me this error on a react project.

> Component should be written as a pure function (react prefer/stateless
> function)

It points to the first line of the component.

```
export class myComponent extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (

      //stuff here

    );
  }
}
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Write it as a pure function or disable the error for that line?

Comment: how would I change it to a pure function?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Two choices.

**Temporarily disable warning**

*<sup>(Untested; and there are multiple ways to do this.)</sup>*

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react/prefer-stateless-function
export class myComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

**Use a pure stateless component**

The return value is what will be rendered (e.g., you're basically writing class-based component's `render` method:

```
export const myComponent = () => {
  return (
    // JSX here
  )
}
```

(Or use non-ES6 notation if that's your thing.)

For components like this with no other supporting logic I prefer the implicit return, e.g.,

```
export MyComponent = () =>
  <div>
    // Stuff here
  </div>
```

This is a matter of preference. I would say that you should follow React naming conventions, though, and keep all components starting with an upper-case letter.

*<sup>ESLint may complain about missing parens around a multi-line JSX expressions, so disable that rule or use parens.</sup>*

If you need props, they're passed in as the argument to the function:

```
const MyComponent = (props) =>
  <div>
    <Something someProp={props.foo} />
  </div>

export MyComponent
```

And you can destructure in the parameter as usual for convenience:

```
const MyComponent = ({ foo }) =>
  <div>
    <Something someProp={foo} />
  </div>
```

This can make the implicit return a little easier if you were using local vars. You'll get an ESLint warning about missing `PropTypes` unless you declare them; since it's not a class you cannot simply use `static propTypes` in the class, they must be attached to the function (which many people prefer anyway).

Comment: what if it is connected? (wrapper with connection function)

Comment: @JasonG I'm not sure what you're asking out of context and from something from this long ago. But connecting doesn't change the component declaration; it wraps the component so that props come from the Redux state.

Comment: so you would pass in the props as the argument and leave your connection function exactly how it is?

Comment: @JasonG I'm still not sure what you're asking: components are written the same way whether or not they're connected.

Answer (score 10):

Add `constructor()` like:

```
exports class myComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding state like this:
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {}
}
worked for me.

Comment: This adds a useless constructor and a useless state.

Answer (score 5):

Write your component as a stateless function:

```
export myComponent = () => { //stuff here };
```

There are actually two styles of defining components in React: Functional components (which are just functions from props to a React component) and class components.

The main difference between them is that class components can have `state` and lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc.

Whenever you don't need state of lifecycle methods, you should write your component as a stateless function, as stateless components are in general easier to reason about.

To write a functional component, you write a function that takes a single argument. This argument will receive the component's props. Consequently, you don't use `this.props` to access the component's props - you just use the function's argument.

Comment: Until React comes up with some kind of optimizations for SFC, they should be avoided as they do not prevent wasteful renders.

Answer (score 5):

If you rely on `props`, then there is a better (somewhat arguable, as of this writing) way to fix this error without writing out Stateless functions - by writing a [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) and using this eslint rule  [[source]](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prefer-stateless-function.md#ignorepurecomponents):

```
"react/prefer-stateless-function": [2, { "ignorePureComponents": true }],
```

With above rule, the following snippet is valid (since it depends on `props`)

```
class Foo extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>;
  }
}
```

React team plans to build optimizations around SFC but they are not there yet. So until that happens, `SFCs` will not offer any benefits over `PureComponents`. In fact, they will be slightly worse as they will not prevent wasteful renders.

Comment: is there a github issue to follow about SFC optimization? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure. It's somewhere in their docs too. Also, see this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is rendering a jsx template, and not declaring state with `constructor(props)`, then you should write your component as a pure function of props, and not use the `class` keyword to define it.

ex.

```
export const myComponent = () => (
   // jsx goes here  
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error only when your class does not have any life cycle method or constructor.
To solve this either you have to disable the lint property or make it as a pure function or create constructor for the class.

Comment: (Isn't that what everybody said back in April?)

Answer (score 2):

```
const myComponent = () => {
return (
  //stuff here

  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

And in app.js file just import this component as we do for class like

```
import myComponent from './myComponent.js'
```

and call as

```
<myComponent />
```

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
export class myComponent extends PureComponent {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add constructor(props)

```
export class myComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {};
        }
    render() {
        return (
    
          //stuff here
    
        );
      }
    }
```